# how can I create a dynamic grid in js and css

Tags: javascript, css, grid-layout

I am facing a problem related with the creation of a dynamic grid. But the cells are in the same column and there is no more columns as shown in the image below. Thanks in advance!
note: I tried the same code in an online editor and works perfectly, so I am not sure the reason why it does not working in a Wordpress website.

[image: 1]

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1 fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1 fr);
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```
function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  var colors = [];
  while (colors.length < (rows * cols)) {
    do {
        var color = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000)+1);
    } while (colors.indexOf(color) >= 0);
    colors.push("#" + ("000000" + color.toString(16)).slice(-6));
  }
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    cell.style.background=colors[c]
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
    
  };
};

makeRows(2, 2);
```

```
<div id="container"> </div>
```

Comment: `1 fr` should be `1fr` .. the value you used is invalid. Plus you should have the container element with empty content (remove the white space between the tags). Once you'll made those corrections the grid will correctly show a 2*2 layout

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem... instead of using 1 fr I used:                            
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), minmax(15px,35px));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), minmax(15px,35px));
and know is working! (apart of the space in the container div...

Comment: yes but sticking with the code in the question, using `1fr` instead of `1 fr` corrected the problem. Now if you want to use `minmax` over fixed units it's ok as well but it's changing the question conditions. The white space in the div was just screwing the layout. It was a minor issue but yet it was affecting the layout. For the sake of completeness `1fr` will be availableWidth/cols while fixed units won't go beyond that width number chosen. But that's something you know already